# Underscore.js JSON context - looping construct?

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template

```
<tbody id="userInfoDetails">
           <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">            
           {{#each usersInfo}}
                <tr>
                  <td class="username">{{screenname}}</td>
                  <td class="realName">{{realname}}</td>
                  <td class="email">{{email}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
    </script>
     </tbody>
```

My JSON context :

```
var response = [{
    "usersInfo": [{
            "id": 0,
            "email": "user0@live.com",
            "realname": "user0",
            "screenname": "mash0",
            "mention": "false"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "user1@live.com",
            "realname": "user1",
            "screenname": "mash1",
            "mention": "false"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "user2@live.com",
            "realname": "user2",
            "screenname": "mash2",
            "mention": "false"
        } ]
}]
```

and the render function:

```
   var source   = $("#some-template").html();
   var template = Handlebars.compile(source);                
   $("#userInfoDetails").html(template(response));
```

But I dont get the expected html for rendering. In fact with this code, template(response) returns empty.

Any suggestions.?

Answer (score 0):

Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7344483/1342296.

In your case. Either change the JSON response server side, or template only the first object.

```
 $("#userInfoDetails").html(template(response[0]));
```