# Display in meteorjs page a json object value with numeric name

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like to display the value 10 of this object {'1':10}, but I cannot find the right syntax for the template.
Client `js` code is:

```
  Template.hello.data = function () {
    return { '1' : 10};
   };
```

Client `html` code is:

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>
<template name="hello">
  <p>{{data.1}}</p>
</template>
```

This gives the error:

```
hello.html:6: Expected IDENTIFIER
<p>{{data.1}}</p>
```

Of course changing to something like `{ 'A1' : 10}` it works, but I would like to keep the field name `'1'`.

Comment: I guess that would be `{{data.[1]}}`

Comment: Wouldn't it be `{{data['1']}}`? Does bracket notation work in handlebars html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the data parser is treating the 1 as an integer rather than a string. Try bracket notation (see answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12272511/1327678)

```
{{data.[1]}}
```

Comment: I expected `{{data.['1']}}` worked: it gives no error, but does show nothing. `{{data.[1]}}` works.